# JavaFX как вызвать метод контроллера из другого класса

Tags: javafx

Здравствуйте, не получается вызвать метод set_text контроллера из другого класса.
В Java новичок рассчитываю на вашу помощь!

Код Controller.java:

```
 public class Controller {

    @FXML
    private TextField text_editor;

    public void set_text(ActionEvent actionEvent) {
        text_editor.setText("test");
    }
}
```

Код Test.java:

```
  public class Test {
    Controller controller = new Controller();

    public void setController(Controller controller) {
        this.controller = controller;
        controller.set_text();
    }
}
```

Comment: Тут вариантов несколько: не в `FX` потоке, несколько экземпляров класса, ещё что-нибудь. Так же непонятна суть вопроса - что значит не получается вызвать? Минимальный воспроизводимый пример бы.